# Saving .tif Image Incorrectly using Python3 and imageio

Tags: python, image, tiff, zstack

I am trying to save an altered z-stack .tif file in Python3.  Here's my code where I checked that the the functions worked as intended.

```
#libraries
import imageio as ii

#import initial image
fname='101_nuc1syg1.tif'
adata = ii.volread(fname)

#check to make sure volread works
ii.volsave('temp.tif', adata)
```

Which results in this:

[image]

And now when I try to do a simple threshold, using the following code:

```
#now doing very simple thresholding
bdata  = adata < adata[0].mean()

bdata = bdata +0

ii.volsave('temp.tif', bdata)
```

I get this:

[image]

Any idea how to save a tif file properly after performing image operators on it?

EDIT: Note that I am able to extract each stack and save them as separate .png files, but I would prefer to have them as a single .tif file.

Data from: https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-020-15987-2

Comment: I get the following result:

>>> bdata = bdata.astype('unit8') +0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>


"Properly" means that each stack in the .tif should be a binary image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to convert `bdata` type to `np.uint8` and multiply the result by 255.

- The type of the expression (adata < adata[0].mean()) is `np.bool`.
  The common image type is `np.uint8`.
  Convert `(adata < adata[0].mean())` to type `np.uint8`:

  ```
   bdata  = (adata < adata[0].mean()).astype(np.uint8)
  ```
- When converting the result to `np.uint8`, all `True` elements are converted to `1` and False elements are converted to `0`.
  Multiply by `255` for converting the `True` elements to `255` (white color):

  ```
   bdata = bdata * 255
  ```

---

Complete code:

```
import imageio as ii
import numpy as np

#import initial image
fname='101_nuc1syg1.tif'
adata = ii.volread(fname)

#now doing very simple thresholding
bdata  = (adata < adata[0].mean()).astype(np.uint8)

bdata = bdata * 255  # Convert ones to 255 (255 is white color)

ii.volsave('temp.tif', bdata)
```

Note:
I could not test my answer - the link you have posted doesn't contain a link to an image.